# Snowflake JavaScript procedure how to update a field from an object that is not in a stage?

Tags: javascript, sql, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to do a JavaScript procedure on Snowflake to update a table with relevant values in a JavaScript array.

Assume that I have the following table:

[image]

And having this array:

```
var arr = {"gender_value": "Gender", "age_range": "Age Range"}
```

So the final result of my updated table would be:

[image]

I tried something like:

```
var query = "
    MERGE INTO mytable m
    USING (SELECT * FROM "+arr+" )
";
```

But I don't think it is possible to SELECT from an object if it is not in a stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to have to parse your array in SQL to get structure for the MERGE.  Another alternative is to store array in temporary table.  But I don't see any issues getting this to work, see my example:

```
create or replace table so_test
(
question_name varchar
,answer varchar
,question_label varchar
);

insert into so_test values ('gender_value','Female',null),('age_range','>60',null);

merge into so_test
using 
(
select 
g.key as join_key
,g.value as join_value
from  
(
select parse_json(column1) as arr from values ('{"gender_value": "Gender", "age_range": "Age Range"}') 
) x,
lateral flatten(input => x.arr) g
)src
on so_test.question_name = src.join_key
when matched then update
set question_label = src.join_value;

--proc example
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "ARRAY_TEST_SP"(sp_input varchar)
RETURNS VARCHAR(16777216)
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS 
$$
var v_array = SP_INPUT;
var v_merge = `merge into so_test
using 
(
select 
g.key as join_key
,g.value as join_value
from  
(
select parse_json(column1) as arr from values (?) 
) x,
lateral flatten(input => x.arr) g
)src
on so_test.question_name = src.join_key
when matched then update
set question_label = src.join_value;`;
var v_stmt = snowflake.createStatement( 
  {
  sqlText:  v_merge,
  binds:[v_array] 
  }
);
try {
        v_stmt.execute()
        return "Succeeded.";   // Return a success/error indicator.
        }
    catch (err)  {
        return "Failed: " + err;   // Return a success/error indicator.
        }
$$;

call ARRAY_TEST_SP('{"gender_value": "Gender", "age_range": "Age Range"}');
```